# Copy file with a new file name

Tags: macos, applescript

My boss has asked me to write an AppleScript that with a file, specified with a hard coded path in the text script, Copy a file from one location in the Finder to another location (giving it a new file name in the process).

This was my idea

```
tell application "Finder"
    copy "/blah/blahblah/ 
    save as "blah blah2" /blah/blah/blah
end tell
```

Comment: Google is your friend [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2810276](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2810276)

Answer (score 0):

`Copy` is an AppleScript command not a finder command,

`copy 1 to a`

will copy value 1 into variable `a`

The command you're looking for to copy files is `duplicate`.

```
set fileToCopy to "DiskName:Users:shortname:Downloads:document.pdf"
set targetFolder to "DiskName:Users:shortname:Desktop:"
tell application "Finder" to duplicate fileToCopy to folder targetFolder
```

Comment: error "Finder got an error: Can’t make \"Macintosh HD:MacTech:Desktop:ROFL.txt\" into type item." number -1700 from "Macintosh HD:MacTech:Desktop:ROFL.txt" to item I get this error when I try to copy the file :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the downvotes!

Any who'zle this is what I ended up with

```
set desktopFolder to path to desktop as text
set thefile to desktopFolder & "lol.html"
set DestinationPath to desktopFolder & "BLAH BLAH BLAH"
set destinationFilename to "ROFL2.txt"
with timeout of 60 seconds
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set theDupe to duplicate file thefile to folder DestinationPath
        set name of theDupe to destinationFilename
    on error
        display dialog "A problem occurred duplicating the file. This may be because the file already exists!"
    end try
end tell
end timeout
```